# Is there a way to reuse layouts between dynamic templates in Sendgrid?

Tags: templates, handlebars.js, sendgrid

We are using Sendgrid and dynamic templates for our service. We have many different communications going over email to our customers quite frequently, so we have over 20 different templates.

I want to reuse the same header, footer and CSS between these templates to avoid typos and make updates easier. Is there any way to use handlebar layouts or partials with Sendgrid Dynamic templates to allow me to do this?

Or is there another good solution or tool that can help? It's not that it is impossibly hard to update this manually, but it is tedious.

Kind regards,
David

Answer (score 1):

I created a helper tool in NodeJS to help generate templates from a layout + content and then uploaded this, overriding existing versions or creating new ones.

Please see:
https://github.com/ddikman/sendgrid-dynamic-templates